# 2x6 as floor joist

Tags: joists, subfloor, remodeling

I am going to be replacing the subfloor in a room, but just noticed that the exiting joists at the end wall (room getting new subfloor is a dining room, room next to it is a bathroom) end at unfortunate spots. The wall is just about in the middle of the floor between these two joists, which means I either have to demo the bathroom or end the subfloor a foot earlier than I want.

So, my question: can I use a 14’ (I am able to add a post at about 9’) 2x6 (because of space restrictions) to act as the end joist for a new subfloor? I could double them up, but anything larger than 2x6 will not fit.

Comment: Are you saying you are going to span 9’ with a 2x6 as a floor joists?

Comment: Yes, sorry. 9’ and 5’ I guess

Comment: I answered for a 2x6 joist, but if you are asking for rim joists, beams or girder you'd have to provide a sketch with dimensions and location of support points.

Comment: Does the new post being added have footing?

Comment: @LeeSam no, no footing over here

Comment: @LeeSam also worth noting, most of the existing joists are 20-24” apart. Super old construction. This new joist would be about 14” from one joist and 10” from the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use 2x6 for a 9' span, if the joists are spaced 16" OC.

Ref: https://www.mycarpentry.com/joist-span-table.html

[image]

Comment: Nice chart easy to understand.